# How to load pdf files from url using react-pdf-viewer or some other library with search button?

Tags: react-pdf-viewer

I am trying to load pdf from url using react-pdf-viewer library. I need a search button therefore I use this library. Is it possible to load pdf from url in this library? Or should I use any other library?

My current implementation is

```
const pdfFile = require("../assets/pdf/mypdf.pdf");

return (
        <Worker workerUrl="https://unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@2.6.347/build/pdf.worker.min.js">
          <div style={{ height: "720px", marginTop: "120px" }}>
            <Viewer fileUrl={pdfFile} plugins={[defaultLayoutPluginInstance]} />
          </div>
        </Worker>
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Most react `react-pdf-viewer` libraries like this syncfusion one ***according to its demo*** is a hybrid where search can be at two levels both internal and external, here we can see the two text layers subject to a search and the result by search in the browser.

[image]

You specify one that appears to be similar based on PDF.js which should have an internal spyglass https://codesandbox.io/s/react-pdf-viewer-sample-yc8ut?file=/public/pdf-open-parameters.pdf

[image]

So most react js based libraries should offer one or the other, if not both. (but beware it's not always the real pdf which is in the back end)

[image]

Here is a windows binary PDF client viewer with same URL
[image]

Comment: Sorry sir but I didn't understand, can you explain it in more detail? Or is there a react library which you can suggest for both "opening pdf file from url" and "having search functionality"?